# Finder URL interpretation

Tags: swift, macos, drag-and-drop

In this routine - tableView validateDrop, I need to understand the items returned. The return items array appears to be file ids?

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, validateDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, 
proposedRow row: Int, proposedDropOperation dropOperation: NSTableViewDropOperation) -> NSDragOperation {
    print("validate drop \(dropOperation)")
    if dropOperation == .Above {
        //get the file URLs from the pasteboard
        let pasteboard = info.draggingPasteboard()

        //list the file type UTIs we want to accept
        let options = [NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey : true,
                       NSPasteboardURLReadingContentsConformToTypesKey : [kUTTypeMovie as String]]
        let items = pasteboard.readObjectsForClasses([NSURL.classForCoder()],
                                                         options: options)
        if items!.count > 0 {
            for item in items! {
                print("item -> \(item)")
            }

            print("validate Above -> .Copy")
            return .Copy;

        } else {

            print("validate Above -> .Move")
            return .Move

        }
    }
    print("validate other -> .None")
    return .None
}
```

which outputs:

```
item -> file:///.file/id=6571367.34508463
```

At some point I need to translate this to what I can use - a typical file:// formatted URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

duh

```
po item.filePathURL
▿ Optional<NSURL>
  - Some : file:///Users/slashlos/Movies/Flight%20to%20Mars.m4v
```

which I'd probably unescape for user viewing